After protecting an Excel worksheet with VBA, selected cells are not "Outlined"
After I use the following code to Protect/ReProtect a worksheet, or workbook (as passed in the arguments). The typical "Selection highlighting is missing. The Highlight that I mean is the surrounding "halo" around the selection.
This situation disappears when you move to another worksheet and back. I at first thought it was the activation of another worksheet that triggered the return to normalcy, but this also happens when you switch from the worksheet to the VBE and back. Something is refreshing the worksheet?
I have used all sorts of combination of "Application.ScreenUpdating" and Application.EnableEvents without any luck.
Public Sub Protect_Me(Optional ws As Worksheet, Optional ResetRibbon As Boolean = True)
' Reverse the UNProtection of UnProtect_Me(), for the whole workbook, or only one specific worksheet
 
Dim wrksht As Excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    Sheet1.Range("X14") = (FindLastRow(Sheet1) - 4)
    Sheet1.Range("X15") = (FindLastRow(Sheet2) - 6)
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then   ' No parameter supplied, protect every sheet
        For Each wrksht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            With wrksht
                If .CodeName = "Sheet9" Or .CodeName = "Sheet2" Then
                    .EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
                ElseIf .CodeName = "Sheet8" Then
                    With Sheet8
                        .Range("A1:E2").Locked = True
                        .Range("A3:E" & FindLastRow(Sheet8)).Locked = False
                        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
                    End With
                Else
                    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
                End If

                .Protect Password:=Protection_pwd, AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                    UserInterFaceOnly:=True
            End With
        Next
       
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:=Protection_pwd, Structure:=True, Windows:=True
         
    Else    ' We only protect the worksheet (ws)
        With ws
            If .CodeName = "Sheet9" Or .CodeName = "Sheet2" Then
                .EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
            ElseIf .CodeName = "Sheet8" Then
                With Sheet8
                    .Range("A1:E2").Locked = True
                    .Range("A3:E" & FindLastRow(Sheet8)).Locked = False
                    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
                End With
            Else
                .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
            End If

            .Protect Password:=Protection_pwd, AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        End With
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:=Protection_pwd, Structure:=True, Windows:=True
        
    End If
        
    GoTo cleanup
    
cleanup:
    
    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectWindows = True Or ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Then
        Sheet1.Range("T15").value = True
    Else
        Sheet1.Range("T15").value = False
    End If
          
    ' Release some memory
    Set wrksht = Nothing

    ' If the argument is set NOT to refresh the ribbon...exit
    If ResetRibbon = False Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Adjust the Ribbon Protect checkboxes and labels
    Call RefreshRibbon
    
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("There was an error Protecting your worksheet(s). Error description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Click Cancel to ABORT, otherwise...Resuming next...", vbOKCancel, "Error number: " & Err.Number) = vbCancel Then
            Resume cleanup
        Else
            Resume Next
        End If
    Else
        Resume Next
    End If
    
End Sub


did you check on .Protect AllowSelectLockedCells:=True and/or .Protect AllowSelectUnlockedCells:=True. I think Excel only gives the Halo for cells which can be selected.

If you mean the option ".EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells", you can see in the code that I used that one. The Worksheet_SelectionChange event fires and the cell address appears in the "Name box".

No, the ones I mentioned are specific parameters you can pass during the protection of a worksheet. On this site all protection methods are explained: https://myexceldeveloper.com/2024/10/10/protecting-your-excel-workbooks-a-friendly-guide/
